# How to update an HTML string with an element from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to update a stringify HTML element with element from the DOM.
This stringify HTML element is in an array in the localStorage.

First, here is how I convert it into manipulable HTML :

```js
let toBeUpdated = document.createElement('div');
toBeUpdated.innerHTML = `${var_stringify_html_from_localstorage}`;
toBeUpdated = toBeUpdated.firstElementChild;
```

This `toBeUpdated` element is a div that contains, among other thing, an element with id `updateMe`.
I want to update this "virtual" (not visible) `#updateMe` element with the one from the DOM.

I tried first :

```js
let updateme = toBeUpdated.querySelector("#updateMe");
let updateme_DOM = document.querySelector("#updateMe");

toBeUpdated.replaceChild(updateme, updateme_DOM);
```

Which returns  `Uncaught DOMException: Node.replaceChild: Child to be replaced is not a child of this node`

And secondly I tried :

```js
let updateme = toBeUpdated.querySelector("#updateMe");
let updateme_DOM = document.querySelector("#updateMe");

updateme.replaceWith(updateme_DOM);
```

Which removes the originale `#updateMe` from the DOM and dosn't update the `toBeUpdated` element.

I'm obviously missing something, but I can't see what...

I tried to reproduce as much as possible my situation :

```js
//initial state of local storage
let motd = ["<div id='toBeUpdated'><h1>Hello World</h1><p id='updateMe'>Message of tomorrow</p></div>"];
window.localStorage.setItem('motds', JSON.stringify(motd));

// My situation, later in the code
let motds = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('motds'));
let toBeUpdated = document.createElement('div');
toBeUpdated.innerHTML = `${motds[0]}`;
toBeUpdated = toBeUpdated.firstElementChild; // this is the div#toBeUpdated

let DOMUpdateMe = document.getElementById('updateMe');
let storageUpdateMe = toBeUpdated.querySelector("#updateMe"); // getElementById doesn't work here

// Replace
storageUpdateMe.replaceWith(DOMUpdateMe);

// Back in local storage
motds[0] = toBeUpdated.outerHTML;
window.localStorage.setItem('motds', JSON.stringify(motds));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="toBeUpdated">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p id="updateMe">Message of tomorrow</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `updateme.replaceWith(updateme_DOM);` shouldnt this be the other way around `updateme_DOM.replaceWith(updateme);`

Comment: thanks @Breezer but what I want is to update my "virtual" (not really in the DOM) element, not the DOM the user is seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only thing you're missing is cloning the DOM node before inserting it into the non-DOM.

Here's a step-by-step reproduction of your code changing only this, that works. I also set the initial state of `localStorage` to "Message of today" for clarity.

*`localStorage` is emulated with variables, as it triggers a security error inside snippet due to CORS*

```js
//initial state of local storage
let motd = ["<div id='toBeUpdated'><h1>Hello World</h1><p id='updateMe'>Message of today</p></div>"];
//window.localStorage.setItem('motds', JSON.stringify(motd));

//Read from local storage
//let motds = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('motds'));
const motds = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(motd)); //Simulate local storage
console.log("In storage:", motds);

//Create element outside of DOM
const toBeUpdated = document.createElement('div');
toBeUpdated.innerHTML = motds[0];
console.log("To be updated:", toBeUpdated.outerHTML);

//Get part to update
const DOMUpdateMe = document.getElementById('updateMe');
const storageUpdateMe = toBeUpdated.querySelector("#updateMe");
console.log(DOMUpdateMe, storageUpdateMe);
//Replace part outside of DOM with clone of part from DOM
storageUpdateMe.replaceWith(DOMUpdateMe.cloneNode(true));
console.log(toBeUpdated.outerHTML);

//Store back
motds[0] = toBeUpdated.outerHTML;
motd = JSON.stringify(motds); //Simulate local storage
console.log(motd);
//window.localStorage.setItem('motds', JSON.stringify(motds));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="toBeUpdated">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p id="updateMe">Message of tomorrow</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're a life saver. And bonus, you corrected my example. Really a big thank you, I would never have found the `.cloneNode(true)` method.

Answer (score 1):

It works using `firstChild` rather than `firstElementChild`

```js
let toBeUpdated = document.createElement('div');
//toBeUpdated.innerHTML = `${var_stringify_html_from_localstorage}`;
toBeUpdated.innerHTML = `<div id="updateMe">New DIV</div>`;
let updateme = document.getElementById('updateMe')
updateme.replaceWith(toBeUpdated.firstChild);
```

```html
<div id='updateMe'>Old DIV</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kinglish but I try to archive the other way around, see my updated post. The variable in the locale storage is actually here to cache a list of elements, that I want to update (don't want to update the DOM)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using a simple `newUpdateMe = DOMUpdateMe;`

```js
//initial state of local storage
let motd = ["<p class='updateMe'>Message of the day<p>"];
window.localStorage.setItem('motds', JSON.stringify(motd));

// My situation, later in the code
let motds = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('motds'));
let dOMUpdateMe = document.querySelectorAll('#toBeUpdated > *');

let counter = 0;
dOMUpdateMe.forEach(function(dOMToUpdate) {
  console.log(dOMToUpdate);
  if(dOMToUpdate.classList.contains('updateMe')) {
    motds[counter] = dOMToUpdate.outerHTML;
    counter++;
  }
})
window.localStorage.setItem('motds', JSON.stringify(motds));
```

```html
<div id="toBeUpdated">
  <h1 class="updateMe">Hello World</h1>
  <p class="updateMe">Update Me</p>
  <p class="no">No not Update Me</p>
  <p class="no">No not Update Me</p>
  <p class="no">No not Update Me</p>
  <p class="updateMe">Update Me too</p>
  <p class="no">No not Update Me</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, that is what I did first, and it worked. But the #toBeUpdated content is dynamic (some elements only show in certain condition), so I only want to update this #updateMe element that is always visible but its value might change (the actual element in my website is a ratio of up-vote/down-vote, and some buttons that change of color and do thing when clicking on them)

Comment: What is preventing you from a conditional checking whether or not the toBeUpdated is visible when adding items on the localStorage?

Comment: I just want to update #updateMe, without updating the rest of #toBeUpdated.
toBeUpdated is always visible (it's a post, like in a social network), it has some child elements that may be invisible. For example, a button to see the comments that is only visible on the feed, but not on the actual post page. I don't need to update the whole post (toBeUpdated) in the local storage, just some parts (up/down vote button, here represented by #updateMe)

Comment: You should use a class for updateMe then. I updated the answer.

Comment: I updated the code. It should be clearer.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been clear, I store the whole #toBeUpdated as a string in local storage, but when I update it, I update only some parts (#updateMe). I do this because I restore #toBeUpdated later in the process, not only restore the #updateMe parts. I could have restored only the moving parts (#updateMe), but I don't have time to change the whole restore mechanism.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I get it. Just a question, is this array really just one element or is it two elements and you just missed the coma? `let motd = ["<div id='toBeUpdated'><h1>Hello World</h1><p id='updateMe'>Message of tomorrow</p></div>"];`